# Blending an image together with a control's background

Tags: c#, image-processing, transparency, gdi+, blending

I'm trying to blend an image with reduced opacity together with a control's background. The code I'm using is the following one:

```
ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]{
    new float[] {1F, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    new float[] {0, 1F, 0, 0, 0},
    new float[] {0, 0, 1F, 0, 0},
    new float[] {0, 0, 0, opacity, 0}, //opacity in rage [0 1]
    new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1F}});

ImageAttributes imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
imageAttributes.SetColorMatrix(matrix);

g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
//g comes with the background already painted on it; img is my Bitmap
g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes);
```

Speed Performance is good but quality has problems especially with dark images. Following two images for background (left) and foreground(right):
[image]
when using an opacity of 0.9 for the foreground produce the output on the left here below. Same images with Photoshop and 90% opacity on foreground produce a more consistent result (right).
[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is it just a limitation of the `ImageAttribute` method? If the problem is the method I'm using, can you please suggest alternatives that still keep in mind performances? Possibly, the alternative should also consider that I receive the background already painted on the `Graphics` object.

**Edit**
To make it clear, the problem is that at 90% of opacity the dark portions (only those!) of the image are too much transparent. If this would hold for any color, then I could just apply a factor to the opacity value, however with light colors it works (see light bulb) and with dark it does not.

Comment: I don't think Adobe software, at least not Photoshop, does blending in RGB mode, so you would expect slightly different results. I don't know why you think the Photoshop result is "more consistent"; it is just different.

Comment: In my opinion it is not different, it seems more that it does not work properly (or at least as expected). Please check my edit

Comment: How exactly do blend with photoshop? Just overlaying? Or some blending mode?

Comment: Just overlapping. However, I do not demand to have the same result than in Photoshop. I took it just as an example to show how a reasonable transparent effect should be. The main problem is the different behaviour between light and dark colors

Comment: You'll have to make the background color the transparency color.  Use Bitmap.MakeTransparent(Color).  If you have no idea what color that might be then GetPixel(0, 0) is usually a good guess.

Comment: @HansPassant background and images can have different colors (within the same image too).

Comment: Well, hopefully they do.  It doesn't change my comment.  Did you try?

Comment: @HansPassant sorry but I'm not understanding how to do. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try CompositingQuality.GammaCorrected? It looks to me as if the compositing is not gamma corrected.

You may also wish to experiment with the ImageAttributes.SetGamma method.

Comment: Try ImageAttributes.SetGamma.

Comment: Thanks but I miss knowledge on gamma. If I use ImageAttributes.SetGamma(x) nothing changes; if I use ImageAttributes.SetGamma(x, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap) the image is fully opaque. I tried x = 1, 2 and 5.